# How to rename an image file in uploading process

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, pdo

I want to do is rename the file name of the image before the file will be move to upload folder and save the link to database.

My problem is in my current code the original name of the file remains after it move to upload folder and even in saving the link to database the original image name is remain.

How do i make the original name of the image file rename before it will move to the upload folder and before the link is save to the database?

example: original name `Oppa/upload/default.png`

i want to rename it `Oppa/upload/1.png`

php code:

```
<?php
include_once('../dbc/database.php');

$db = new Connection();
$db = $db->dbConnect();
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$imageLink = isset($_POST['imageLink']) ? $_POST['imageLink'] : "";

$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : "";

$image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['imageInput']['tmp_name']));
$image_name = addslashes($_FILES['imageInput']['name']);
$image_size = getimagesize($_FILES['imageInput']['tmp_name']);

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imageInput"]["tmp_name"], "../upload/" . $_FILES["imageInput"]["name"]);
$location = "Oppa/upload/" . $_FILES["imageInput"]["name"];


if(!empty($_POST['imageLink'])) {

        $q = "UPDATE tbl_user SET user_image = '$location' WHERE user_email= :email ";
        $query = $db->prepare($q);
        $query->bindParam(':email', $email);
        $results = $query->execute();
        echo "1";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try as below:

```
$type = $_FILES["imageInput"]["type"];
$ext = end(explode('/', $type));
$filename = uniqid() . '.' . $ext; // you can set name here whatever you want
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imageInput"]["tmp_name"], "../upload/" . $filename);
$location = "Oppa/upload/" . $filename;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$image_name = "my_img.jpeg";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imageInput"]["tmp_name"], "../upload/" . $image_name);
$location = "Oppa/upload/" . $image_name;
```

This will save the file withe new name defined in image_name variable